# Configuring Virtuoso cartridges

Tags: rdf, virtuoso

Could anyone please advise me on how to configure the Virtuoso cartridges properly? I followed the documentation for LinkedIn cartridge recently (the site has been updated since the article was written) to configure its extractor cartridge (added key and secret), and still am unable to pull data from my profile (after giving authorization).

Also for other websites, like Google news, BBC, Wikipedia I am not getting the full information, like for example I searched for Mr. Barack Obama on Wiki and did the about/data/xml option on both my server and Uriburner, and it was surprising that the server generated more data than Uriburner but I still did not get the tagged data like birth-date or spouse etc. It seems that the cartridges (extractor OR meta???) are not configured properly.

I have been stuck here for sometime (earlier with Facebook cartridge - no luck still) and would be grateful for your advise.

Answer (score 0):

There is no short answer possible here.

The long answer is that you should refer to --

1. [Virtuoso Sponger documentation](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtSponger)
2. [OpenLink Virtuoso support forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/index.php)
3. [OpenLink Virtuoso users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users)
4. [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/)'s [support site and case system](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp)

Comment: TallTed, the problem is that even when you use the public URI burner (so, no configuration), there is no problem with Twitter, but with LinkedIn I get "HTTP/1.1 999 Request denied".

Comment: @IvoVelitchkov's comment is not directly related to this question. URIBurner's credentials for LinkedIn lookup had expired. Credential update is pending.

Comment: Thanks a lot. (and by the way, I think the question is relevant. In process of configuring the Virtuoso cartridges, we are also testing the public URI Burner. Both our and the public don't work for LinkedIn, while when ours doesn't work for Twitter, the public one does, and that's useful to know when we are trying to find out what's going on)